# Ambiguous call to overloaded function - std::to_string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, c++11, overloading

In attempting to insert integer values into a string, I thought that my prayers were answered when I found std::to_string, but for some reason whenever I actually try to use it, Visual Studio complains about ambiguity.  Here is the current incarnation of my function:

```
string get_time_remaining (int elapsed)
{
    string remaining;
    string temp_string;

    int time_remaining = TimeLimit - elapsed;

    int temp_int;

    temp_int = int(time_remaining / 3600);

    if(temp_int == 0)
        remaining = "00 : ";
    else
    {
        temp_string = std::to_string(temp_int);   // Here!
        remaining = temp_string + " : ";
    }

    temp_int = time_remaining % 60 + 1;

    if(temp_int < 10)
        remaining = remaining + "0";

    temp_string = std::to_string(temp_int);

    remaining = remaining + temp_string;

    return remaining;
}
```

I have tried casting temp_int inside the call to to_string, and as you can see I even tried casting the result of what should be integer division, but no matter what I do, VS spits this out at me:

```
d:\my programs\powerplay\powerplay\powerplay.cpp(1285): error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(688): could be 'std::string std::to_string(long double)'
1>          d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(680): or       'std::string std::to_string(_ULonglong)'
1>          d:\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(672): or       'std::string std::to_string(_Longlong)'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should also point out there is a matching error for the second call to to_string as well, so it's not limited to just one call.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MSVC11 lacks the proper overloads for `std::to_string` so you have to do a `static_cast` to `unsigned long long` or `long long`

Note that this bug is fixed in the November CTP 2012. Which you can get [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much.  Casting it to "not-int" allowed it to compile.  I'll mark it as answer in 2 minutes, when it lets me do that.

Comment: *"Note that this bug is fixed in the November CTP 2012"* - It should already be fixed in the plain *VS 2012*, especially since the *November CTP* didn't bring any library changes at all. This also makes your tagging of his question to `visual-studio-2012` invalid, since he obviously uses 2010, as can be seen from his compiler output.

Comment: @ChristianRau thank you for catching that -- however on my VS2012 without November CTP I had the same issue with the overloads hence the likely confusion on my behalf.

Comment: @Rapptz Works fine for me without *Nov CTP*. Maybe you tried it with some pre-release beta of *VS 2012*?

Comment: it would be very useful to include actual code.

Answer (score 3):

`temp_int` is a `int` value, and Visual Studio seems to detect only overloads which receive either `double`, `long long` or `unsigned long long` values, so it doesn't know which overload to use, thus the ambiguity (although it would seem intuitive to cast integer to long values)

Either declare `temp_int` as a `long long`, or cast it when invoking the function

Comment: It's `unsigned long long` and `long long` not `long`.

Comment: And it's `long double`, not `double`.