# How to convert an integer to a string

Tags: c++, casting

I want to convert an integer to a string. I tried it this way but this didn't work

```
void foo()
{
    int y = 1;
    string x = static_cast<string>(y);

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function should do it:

```
string x = std::to_string(y);
```

For the opposite, it's [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
int z = std::stoi(y, nullptr, 10);
```

Comment: oh that's cute +1; is that a C++11 thing?

Comment: Note: this is only supported by compilers with C++11 support (which you should probably have, by now).

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, it's new in C++11. For older compilers, your version is the solution to use (and most likely how `to_string` works).

Comment: On MS Visual Studio 2010 C++, I get this error: error C2668: 'std::to_string' : ambiguous call to overloaded function. If I cast x to (long double), everything works ok.  Actually, looks like some other folks had the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617950/ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function-stdto-string  Anyway, not sure this answer will work on all modern compilers. VS 2010 isn't that old. But that's C++, what can you say :).

Comment: VS **2010** is not a full implementation of C++ **2011**.

Answer (score 5):

No that will not work since `int` and `std::string` are not related in any class heirarchy. Therefore a `static_cast` will fail.

An easy way (though not necessarily the fastest way) is to write

```
std::stringsteam ss;
ss << y;
std::string x = ss.str();
```

But, if you have a C++11 compiler, Joachim Pileborg's solution is *much* better.

Answer (score 1):

Can have this :

```
  template <typename T>
  string CovertToString ( T Number )
  {
     ostringstream ss;
     ss << Number;
     return ss.str();
  }
```

Comment: I'd consider calling it something besides `NumberToString()`, since this will work for any object for which such a streaming operator exists.