# C++: convert int to string

Tags: c++, string, types, int

I have an int value out of a slider and want to write that value into a label with this expression

```
ui->label_1->setText(std::to_string(ui->verticalSlider->value()));
```

but i get this error:

> ambiguous call to overloaded function

I think i have to typecast the value, but don't know how.

```
ui->label_1->setText(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(ui->verticalSlider->value())));
```

also didn't work.

Comment: What is the signature of `value()`? Can you post the full error message instead of just that snippet?

Comment: are you using Visual C++? in that case check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664699

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ambiguous call to overloaded function - std::to\_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617950/ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function-stdto-string)

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30916955/edit) your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: looks like Qt, try using QString::number, maybe it got better overloads (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number)

Comment: Yes i have Qt and yes QString::number worked, but what is the problem with the overloads?

ui->label_1->setText(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(ui->verticalSlider->value()))); doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`ui->label_1->setText` needs `QString` and not `std::to_string`.

Try this:

```
ui->label_1->setText(QString::number(ui->verticalSlider->value()));
```

Comment: @Creatronik with `QString::number` causes error *ambiguous call to overloaded function*?

Comment: @Creatronik qt5.4 with c++11?

Comment: No, std::to_string. QString::number works fine
I have c++ 10.

Comment: @Creatronik But why would you want to use `std::to_string(static_cast<int>(...))`?

Comment: Because the compiler told me that the expression is ambiguous and that i would have to cast the datatype, like referred in a linked post in the comments of my initial question.